# Alternatives to LAG() in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I asked this question:

[create partition based on the difference between subsequent row indices in sql server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39503683/4294028)

I am just wondering how this could be done in an older version of sql server, say sql 2008 in which LAG is not a recognised function. Is there anyway to implement the lag function in older versions of SQL??

**EDIT**: perhaps I should have been more explicit, in the solution to the referred question, the lag function is used multiple times, is there a more efficient way than using multiple CTEs to get the same result?

Comment: A CTE (WITH statement) can be used to give each row you are interested in a row_number(), over a suitable SORT BY, then the CTE can be self joined on row = row-1, row = ro1+1

Comment: @AndrewDeighton what if i need to use the lag function more than once, this results in using many CTE's, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: you could make one CTE with multiple different row_number() (ORDER BY on different fields) - then you'd have to join that together multiple times in a join  - it could cause a lot of sorting of a large table though.  You could try sub-queries - that could also run into efficiency problems.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton is it too difficult to create a lag() function that is identical to the 2012 lag() ?

Comment: it's not for me to say it can't be done, but I can't see how to do it as such - otherwise wouldn't people have written something like the lag function when they were developing SQL between 2000 - 2012, for example?

Comment: how many times is Lag used? and do they all use different sort orders?  Some SQL 'additions' seem to be very easily replicated using user functions (the seemingly pointless 'end of month' function for example), but this isn't one of them

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the same concept of `LAG` in older versions, you have to make `left join` on the same table for instance:

```
select *
from A a
left join B b on b.Column = a.Column - 1
```